# Reactive video browser choppy except Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a project, where I have a video as background and that video rewinds due to mouse position on screen on axis x. So in a nutshell, if your cursor is on the left side of screen, video is on 00:00 (0%), if cursor is in the middle, video is on 02:00 (50%), etc... I've got this working with this script:

```
    var mouseX;
    $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX; 

        var timV = $(".video1").get(0).duration;
        var valV = (timV*mouseX/$(window).width());
        var valC = $(".video1").get(0).currentTime;

        $(".video1").get(0).currentTime = valV;
    });
```

I've also created a pen, so you can try that yourself: https://codepen.io/honzis1364/pen/bvBZOB

But the problem is, that video rewind is choppy on some browsers, well most of them. **Safari** is perfect, it is flow video rewind backwards and forwards, no problem even with fast mouse movements from left to right and back. But on **Chrome** it starts rewinding choppy, like every 20 frame or so. And **Firefox** is disaster, it rewinds only after you stop cursor movement, you can try it yourself.

I can upload a video from Safari, if somebody can't test on Safari, it's a perfection in there.

I guess it's a problem of browsers, something like it hasn't got enough memory to show every frame of the video or something like that?

Could somebody please tell me how can I (if so) fix that, so the video rewind would be smooth in every browser like in Safari?

Thanks a lot colleagues!

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because your `mousemove` event is firing too much, and the browser has to keep moving the video cursor to the correct value. Have you tried [throttling](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/throttle/) it? Also, perhaps rounding it to the nearest `.1` value will help with performance, too:

```
var mouseX;
$(document).mousemove($.throttle(100, function(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;

  var vid = $('.video1').get(0);

  var timV = vid.duration;
  var valV = timV * mouseX / $(window).width();
  vid.currentTime = valV.toFixed(1);
}));
```

A proof-of-concept example, using a hotlinked mp4 video (example might not work if the link is taken down):

```js
$(function() {
  var mouseX;
  $(document).mousemove($.throttle(100, function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;

    var vid = $('.video1').get(0);

    var timV = vid.duration;
    var valV = timV * mouseX / $(window).width();
    vid.currentTime = valV.toFixed(1);
  }));
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #333;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#video-background {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js"></script>
<video muted loop id="video-background" class="video1">
  <source src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and your time @Terry ! :) I've never heard about throttling honestly, I've implemented it here: https://codepen.io/honzis1364/pen/WzoBLe and I can see better performance in Chrome, not perfect, but useable, thanks!! But in firefox still no luck, it rewinds only after I stop mouse movement... You've been very helpful Terry, could you please point me just a little bit more, please? :)

Comment: @HonzisNovák Can you evaluate on the phrase "rewinds only after I stop mouse movement"?